# what's the difference between could firestore and cloud storage of firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

what's the difference between could firestore and cloud storage of firebase ? I have to admit I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/):

> Cloud Firestore is a **flexible, scalable database** for mobile, web, and server development from Firebase and Google Cloud Platform. Like Firebase Realtime Database, it keeps your data in sync across client apps through realtime listeners and offers offline support for mobile and web so you can build responsive apps that work regardless of network latency or Internet connectivity.

[Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/):

> Cloud Storage for Firebase is a powerful, simple, and cost-effective object storage service built for Google scale. The Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage add Google security to file uploads and downloads for your Firebase apps, regardless of network quality. You can use our SDKs to **store images, audio, video, or other user-generated content**.